# Mock PreferenceManager with Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, tdd

I am new in Android unit testing and I want to add some unit tests in an existing project. I am using the MVP design architecture. Inside my presenter, I have a call to `PreferenceManager` in order to get the default `SharedPrefences` but it always returns null. I have followed some tutorials and advices across stackoverflow on how to mock `PreferenceManager` and `SharedPreferences` but I can't make it work. This is my presenter class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SettingsPresenterTest {
    @Mock
    private SettingsView mView;
    @Mock
    private LocalConfiguration conf;
    private SettingsPresenter mPresenter;

    public SettingsPresenterTest() {
        super();
    }

    @Before
    public void startUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(LocalConfiguration.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(PreferenceManager.class);


        mPresenter = new SettingsPresenter(mView);


        final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = 
        Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
        final Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);

       Mockito.when(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)).
       thenReturn(sharedPrefs);
    }


    @Test
    public void notificationsEnabledClicked() throws Exception {
        boolean notifsEnabled = false;
        mPresenter.notificationsEnabledClicked(notifsEnabled);

        Mockito.verify(mView).setNotificationsView(notifsEnabled);
    }
}
```

and here is the method where the `SharedPreferences` are returned null

```
public class LocalConfiguration { 
    public TerritoryDto getLastSavedTerritory() {
           SharedPreferences preferences = 
           PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(H.getContext());
           String terrritoryString = preferences.getString(SAVED_TERRITORY, 
           null);
           return 
           SerializerHelper.getInstance().deserialize(terrritoryString, 
           TerritoryDto.class);
    }
}
```

Could you give me some guidelines on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly referring to Android SDK, abstract that out from your presenter logics. What this means is, that instead of performing `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, create an abstraction and ask for `territoryString` from your abstraction.

What will this give to you, is that your presenter won't know about the precense of neither `PreferenceManager` nor `SharedPreferences`, which are from Android SDK, thus you would have enough seams to perform pure unit testing.

Having said this, let's implement the abstractions. Having declared following interface:

```
    public interface Storage {
        @Nullable
        String getSavedTerritory();
    }
```

To which the concrete implementation would be:

```
    public SharedPrefsStorage implements Storage {

        private final SharedPreferences prefs;

        public SharedPrefsStorage(Context context) {
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String getSavedTerritory() {
            return prefs.getString(SAVED_TERRITORY, null);
        }

    }
```

Then your presenter would become something like this:

```
    public class LocalConfiguration { 

        final Storage storage;

        public LocalConfiguration(Storage storage) {
            this.storage = storage;
        }

        public TerritoryDto getLastSavedTerritory() {
               final String territory = storage.getSavedTerritory();

               return SerializerHelper.getInstance().deserialize(territory, TerritoryDto.class);
        }
    }
```

This would give you a seam to perform pure unit testing:

```
    @Test
    void someTest() {
        when(storage.getSavedTerritory()).thenReturn("New York");
        ...
    }
```

No need to worry about mocking `PreferenceManager` anymore.

Comment: Your solution is functional but the sad fact is that I can't change the current code, at least for the moment, since it's a big project and I've been here for about a month so I can't take such a decision. Thank you. though.